# How to make a function to listen to more than one event in a view?

Tags: ember.js

I am having a function like below.

```
saveData: function(event){
   //save data logic
}.on('click')
```

But now i want the same function to get executed on focusOut. Currently i am doing like following. Calling the above function from `focusOut()`

```
focusOut: function(event){
   this.saveData(event)
}
```

But is it possible to add in `on` only may be like following

```
saveData: function(event){
   //save data logic
}.on('click, focusOut')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Ember.aliasMethod`.

```
{
    saveData: function() {},
    focusOut: Em.aliasMethod('saveData')
}
```